# Getting a particular key from an object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, object

I have a array of objects with keys a ,b,c. a has property property1, b has properties property1 and property2 ,c has a property propertycheck. My requirement is I want to get only the key which doesn't have the property1 in it. In this scenario I want the output to be c. Any help is appreciated. Stuck at this point

```
  [
      {
        "a": {
          "property1": "false"
        }
      },
      {
        "b": {
          "property1": "false",
          "property2": "truthy"
        }
      },
      {
        "c": {
          "propertycheck": "required"
        }
      }
 ]
```

Comment: We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post. Until then, the question will be voted to be closed / downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version where you could have many sub key for each of your 3 object.

```
var arr = [
  {
    "a": {
      "property1": "false"
    }
  },
  {
    "b": {
      "property1": "false",
      "property2": "truthy"
    }
  },
  {
    "c": {
      "propertycheck": "required"
    }
  }
]

var arr = arr.filter(function(elem){   //Filter on each object in the array
  var checkKey = true;                 //checkKey will be the return value of filter
  Object.keys(elem).forEach(function(key){  //For each key of elem
    if("property1" in elem[key]){           //If value of key (object) own "property1"
      checkKey = false                      //You want to remove the object from table so return false to filter
    }
  })
  return checkKey
})
```

–

Reference to `Array.filter` https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/filter

Comment: using `hasOwnProperty` to check once if the key exists in the filter loop would spare you the complexity of the inner forEach loop.

Answer (score 0):

This can do it:

```
d = [
      {
        "a": {
          "property1": "false"
        }
      },
      {
        "b": {
          "property1": "false",
          "property2": "truthy"
        }
      },
      {
        "c": {
          "propertycheck": "required"
        }
      }
]

d.filter(function(x){
   if(!x[Object.keys(x)[0]].hasOwnProperty("property1"))
    {return x}
})
```

---

#### Explanation:

1. `d.filter` will iterate through the array of object while applying the filtering function
2. `x[Object.keys(x)[0]]` this is used to get the key a, b or c dynamically.
3. `.hasOwnProperty("property1")` will check if the key `property1` is in the the object.

Answer (score -5):

use hasOwnProperty to identify objects with properties .. like this code which will return your object 'c'

```
myObjArr.filter(o => ! o.hasOwnProperty( myPropAsString))
```

Comment: This answer could use more explanation

Comment: my answer came before the accepted answer, and is a more efficient version of the same solution. I can understand that it might have deserved a write up instead of just being a quick solution. I can't understand all the downvotes for what remains to this moment the best solution posted to the question.

Comment: I did not downvote it - just making suggestions to try to get it in the positives